# React FullCalendar - can't get dateClick to work on v5

Tags: reactjs, fullcalendar

I'm using FullCalendar version 5.10.1 and I can't get dateClick to fire despite having interaction plugin

```
export default function MainCalendar() {

  function dateSelectHandler(info) {
    console.log(info);
  }

  return (
     <div>
       <FullCalendar
        dateClick={dateSelectHandler}
        plugins={[dayGridPlugin, timeGridPlugin, interactionPlugin]} />
     </div>
   );
}
```

package.json:

```
    "@fullcalendar/core": "^5.10.1",
    "@fullcalendar/daygrid": "^5.10.1",
    "@fullcalendar/interaction": "^5.10.1",
    "@fullcalendar/react": "^5.10.1",
    "@fullcalendar/timegrid": "^5.10.1",
```

I did managed to get it to work on v4 so I really don't understand what am I doing wrong here

Comment: Were you able to resolve this? Just starting with FullCalendar and running into the same issue, with eventClick as well